# Using NVL function and giving Alias name to same column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, column-alias

While using nvl function i just tried experimenting by adding alias name to column to which nvl is applied but encountered error message .

```
select  nvl(commission_pact,0) commission_pact AS "COMM"
FROM employees;
```

but i am getting error message as :-

> `FROM keyword not found where expected

Where is the problem in syntax?

Answer (score 3):

You are providing two aliases. The second `commission_pact` is already a column alias. Just remove that:

```
select nvl(commission_pact,0) AS "COMM"
FROM employees;
```

alternatively

```
select nvl(commission_pact,0) commission_pact
FROM employees;
```

or

```
select nvl(commission_pact,0) as commission_pact
FROM employees;
```